# DNN: /portals/0-system/cache internal structure folder

Tags: caching, dotnetnuke

I'm trying to analyse IIS logs for an existing web application which is running on DNN 9 (has been migrated along the years) and I'm wondering if anyone can help me understand what's the story with the /portals/portalID/0-system and /portals/portalID/0 folders. It seems like they're used for some sort of caching, but how?

I'm interested in these folders because I've found several requests for an URL on the form (on different days):

/Portals/17-System/Cache/Pages/some_resource.aspx

But there's no file with that name on the folder...

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

File based output caching will save content to the folder. As cache expires the file is deleted.

Comment: Hello again. 

But is there any way to see what's being put there and why?